# In magento How to shorten the product name displaying in breadcrumbs

Tags: magento

Most of the products i have added in magento are being with a very long name.
**For example**:Freelancer BY-022-v1 - the internationally acclaimed trifold design - simple, sleek & functional. 
Hence i am getting the breadcrumb product name as very long.How to shorten this.

**Breadcrumbs**
Home->catalog->Freelancer BY-022-v1 - the internationally acclaimed trifold design - simple, sleek & functional.

How to shorten the product name from the above mentioned breadcrumb

Comment: Hello you will check function getBreadcrumbPath() in  core file path app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php

Comment: if ($this->getProduct()) {
                $path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getName());
            }  This is the function being used in my file to get the product name in breadcrumb.how can i edit the length of product name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data::getBreadcrumbPath`.
Near the end of it there is this:

```
if ($this->getProduct()) {
    $path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getName());
}
```

You can process the value of `$this->getProduct()->getName()` before passing it to `$path['product']`

Comment: Can you pls explain it briefly.where(in which file) i need to update this mehtod?

Comment: @RamaPriya. You need to create a custom module and rewrite the catalog helper in your module. Here is a good tutorial on how to rewrite stuff in magento: http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/

Comment: As i am a beginner in magento its being difficult for me to understand the procedure mentioned in the link.is there any other way to shorten the product name in breadcrumbs?

Comment: @RamaPriya Yeah. Copy the file from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php` and make your changes there. But I strongly recommend that you give that tutorial a try. It's cleaner and safer that way.

Comment: I have copied the file and placed it in this path app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php and updated the code like i v mentioned below                                                    if ($this->getProduct()->getName()) {
                $path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getName());
            }                                                    but still there is no change

Comment: @RamaPriya you need to modify the value `$this->getProduct()->getName())` to fit your needs. That's the product name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42785/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-marius)